# S22 imap fetch mails from office365

Tags: email, ssl, office365, imap

I'm using s22.Imap referance for fetch new mails from server. While read exchange server everything was perfect. But we were moved to office365. Now I can't read new mails from my project. Here is small codes.

```
using (ImapClient client = new ImapClient("outlook.office365.com", 993, user, pass, AuthMethod.Login, true)) {

   // Returns a collection of identifiers of all mails matching the specified search criteria.
   IEnumerable<uint> uids = client.Search(SearchCondition.New());

   // Download mail messages from the default mailbox.
   IEnumerable<MailMessage> messages = client.GetMessages(uids);

   foreach (MailMessage item in messages) { blablabla }
```

This part return this error : `The stream could not be read.`

Lastly I'm using this codes in windows service application. So I'm not clearly debuging.

Is anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Office365 does not support `AuthMethod.Login`. Try `AuthMethod.Plain` or try using a different IMAP library like my [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) library which is more actively maintained.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

its possible but I think that the suscription of the account should be 
Exchange Online, instead of a classic suscription

I do the same with S22 library, but we request to change the configuration of the mail to accept imap conection